# How do i reinstall the android OS?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, recovery-mode, rom, twrp, operating-system

I accidentally wiped my tablets systems firmware in recovery mode which deleted Android it self. ***But* what do I do now?**

more info

Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 7.0

Android version: KitKat 4.4.2

TWRP recovery

That was my Stock Rom. I just need it so that i can revert to it if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things you can do.
But first you have to identify which tablet you are using, if its samsung then install kies and recovery will take you through the process.
Second check your model number xyz whatever.Download the rom to your pc and 
Transfer the downloaded ROM from your computer to your device. You can use the USB cable to perform this task,leave the ROM ZIP file in the root of your phone's SD card; it will make it easier for you to find the file when you need it. 
visit this link you will understand more.
http://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool